# Unspecific boundaries for finding area by double integration

Tags: integration, area

I've been given the boundaries $0≤x≤x^2+y^2≤1$. I have no set equation so it would simply be 1 integrated. Normally I have no problems when the boundaries are clearly divided, yet here I can't seem to figure out what they are for $x$ and $y$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Take $0\le x \le 1$,
Then you have $0 \le \sqrt{1 - x^2} $ as a conditional on $y$.

$$\int \!\! \int_{0 \le x \le x^2 + y^2 \le 1} dx dy = \int_0^1 dx \int_0^\sqrt{1 - x^2} dy$$

Answer (score 0):

Inequality $0 \leqslant x \leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 1$ implies that
$$\begin{cases}
x \geqslant 0,\\
\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2} \right)^2 +y^2 \geqslant \dfrac{1}{4} , \\
x^2+y^2 \leqslant 1 .
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the problem statement more carefully.
Does it really say $0 \leq x \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$?

Notice that

- If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then $x^2 \geq 0$ and $y^2 \geq 0$.
- If $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, then $y^2 \geq 0$ implies $x^2 \leq 1$.
- $x^2 \leq 1$ implies $0 \leq x \leq 1$.
- $0 \leq x \leq 1$ implies $x^2 \leq x$.
- If $x \leq x^2$, then $x^2 \leq x$ implies $x^2 = x$.
- $x^2 = x$ implies that either $x = 0$ or $x = 1$.

In short, the only pairs of real numbers that satisfy the conditions
$0 \leq x \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ 
are the pairs of the form $(0, y)$ for $-1 \leq y \leq 1$
and the pair $(1, 0)$.
In other words, the "region" defined by $0 \leq x \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$
consists of a line segment plus a single point in the $x,y$ plane.
That doesn't sound to me like much of a region of integration.

If that is really what the problem statement says,
I suspect it's a mistake in the problem statement,
which really should have given the conditions as just
$0 \leq x$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.